# TYPO3: meta tag author, how to use both name and email

Tags: typo3, metadata, typoscript

the html5 standard accepts the author tag as name and email:

```
<meta name="author" content="name, email@hotmail.com">
```

The TYPO3 backend allows you to register them both in the Page properties as "Author Name" (field: `author`) and "Author Email" (field: `author_email`),

I know how to include the tag (I use the value recursive):

```
page = PAGE
page {
    meta {
        author.data = levelfield :-1, author slide
        author.override.field = author
    }
}
```

how do I add the email correctly with typoscript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use a `cObject` which concatenates both fields within a COA.

```
page.meta.author.cObject = COA
page.meta.author.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.data = levelfield :-1, author slide
    10.noTrimWrap = ||, |

    20 = TEXT
    20.data = levelfield :-1, author_email slide
    20.noTrimWrap = ||, |

    stdWrap.subString = 0,-2
}
```

As not all fields are ready to slide you need to declare these additional fields for sliding. This can be done in the install tool or an extension.
Solution for an extension: insert in your `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$rootlinefields = &$GLOBALS["TYPO3_CONF_VARS"]["FE"]["addRootLineFields"]; 
if ($rootlinefields != '') { 
    $rootlinefields .= ' , '; 
} 
$rootlinefields .= 'author,author_email';
```

**Attention:**
As `author`  and `author_email` slide independently you might get a mixed content from different pages

Comment: thank you, that got me something working (if you add `10.override.field = author` and `20.override.field = author_email` before you wrap and the subString doesn't work for me, I'm fiddling with `if.isTrue`) but indeed the mixed content is a spoiler ...

Comment: the override(s) should not be neccessary as the `-1` means current level.

Comment: you are probably right, I use ext:t3sbootstrap which might influence, if I do not add it, I get no output ...

Comment: then I doubt the sliding mechanism. have you declared the additions fields for sliding in installtool? add them to `$GLOBALS["TYPO3_CONF_VARS"]["FE"]["addRootLineFields"]`.  otherwise there will be no sliding. (need to copy this to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Bernd I have something half working:

```
page {
    meta {
        author.cObject = COA
        author.cObject {
            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                data = levelfield :-1, author, slide
                override.field = author
                wrap = |
            }

            20 = TEXT
            20 {
                field = author_email
                noTrimWrap = |, ||
                if {
                    isTrue.field = author_email
                    isTrue = 1
                    isTrue.if {
                        isTrue.field = author
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

like this an author will slide, but an email will only be added if there is the combination author and email on the page ...

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted and use it myself on a site! Thanks